# Does Apple permit the usage of socket for communication between two iOS apps?

Tags: ios, sockets, ipc

So basically I have two iOS apps installed on the same device, and they need to communicate by sending data to each other. I don't want to use URL scheme or Universal links as these two would open the other app in UI instead of sending message to each other in the background. Currently I have a solution of using a unix socket connection by binding one app to a specific port and have another app connect to it. This works fine but I am just wondering if Apple would allow the usage of this.
Note that these two iOS apps do not come from the same developer so anything else that relies on App Group would not work in this case..

Would Apple allow using a socket in this case?
Edit: One of the app is valid to run in background, so background execution is not a problem

Comment: Only way to know is to try and get it through the AppStore.. no one here knows what Apple will or will not allow for certain in such a case..

Comment: Even if you could, your app will probably not be running in background. Maybe you can use the shared domain to transmit info between your apps ?

Comment: FYI, that might work if the recipient app happens to be running in the background, but what if it is suspended or terminated (i.e., and, obviously, not attached to Xcode debugger)? Apple is pretty strict about what apps are allowed to do in the background (which is a good thing, as this keeps apps from constantly running in the background, killing our batteries). If you’re keeping an app alive for the sake of interprocess communications, you may run afoul of 2.5.4 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I have valid reason to enable background execution for one of the app, so one app will run in background

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible simply because the application will lose network connectivity when it goes into background mode. I invite you to check the following Apple Developer Documentation page related to iOS app background modes:

[Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

As you can find on the page, the operating system suspend the app when it moves to background and will then cut several resources including network access.

There are however some exceptions to the rule, which are voice ip apps. These must declare the voip background mode in the plist file to be allowed to keep network streams open in the background.

This question comes a lot on iOS or Android and unfortunately the answer so far is no, we can do tcp client / server communication between apps.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I have valid reason to enable background execution for one of the app, so one app will run in background...

Comment: yes, but even if the app runs on background, it will be suspended by the operating system and won't execute code. by default, apps run on the background unless you enable the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend flag in the plist, in which case the app will exit.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally doable as long as one of your apps has permissions to run on the background. Such example is music apps. Spotify does the same thing with their “app-remote” SDK.